# How to replace config directives with str_replace?

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to replace config options in the phpmyadmin ini file, but nothing gets replaced. I tried several combinations of escaping the pattern and the replacement, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php

$pattern = '$cfg[\'Servers\'][$i][\'auth_type\'] = \'cookie\';';

$replacement = '$cfg[\'Servers\'][$i][\'auth_type\'] = \'http\';';

$sContents = '$cfg[\'Servers\'][$i][\'auth_type\'] = \'cookie\';';

str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $sContents);
die($sContents);
```

The output of this snippet is:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

What are the right pattern and replacement to get the following output?

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
$pattern = 'cookie';
$replacement = 'http';
$return = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $sContents);
die($return);
```

Comment: I am so retarted!! Didn't saw that I forgot to put the str_replace output in the $sContents variable -_-'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ini_set to change options in your php ini file.

[See here for more information](https://www.php.net/ini_set)

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving the result of `str_replace`. Simply do that and it works, even without @Mário's short version:

```
$sContents = str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $sContents);
die($sContents);
```